# How to let NestJS controller accept files and body data?

Tags: javascript, typescript, nestjs, form-data

I have a controller accepting some files, and I need to accept additional data.
I have the following controller:

```
    @UseInterceptors(FilesInterceptor('files', 5))
    @Post(Routes.UPLOAD)
    @HttpCode(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public async upload(
        @CurrentUserId() userId: string,
        @Param('group_id') groupId: string,
        @Body() uploadDto: unknown,
        @UploadedFiles(new ParseFilePipe({ validators: [new PoliciesFilesValidator({})] }))
        files: Express.Multer.File[],
    ): Promise<void> {
        console.log(uploadDto);

        await Promise.resolve();
    }
```

I do get the files, but I having problem with getting the rest of the body.

This is how I send the body to the controller from my React app, using the `object-to-formdata` package:

```
import { serialize } from 'object-to-formdata';

        const formData = new FormData();

        const policiesData: IFileServerData[] = [];

        uploadedPoliciesFilesState
            .filter((uploadedFile) => uploadedFile.library !== null)
            .forEach((uploadedFile) => {
                formData.append('files', uploadedFile.file);

                policiesData.push({
                    library: uploadedFile.library!.toUpperCase() as ILibraryUpperCase,
                    filesList: uploadedFile.filesList?.split('\n') ?? [],
                    ignoreList: uploadedFile.ignoreList?.split('\n') ?? [],
                });
            });

        const finalFormData = serialize(policiesData, { allowEmptyArrays: true }, formData, 'policies');

        backendApi.post(`/user/inline-policies/${groupId}`, finalFormData).then(() => {
            setUploadedPoliciesFilesState(() => []);
        });
```

But if I print the body in the nestjs controller I get:

```
{
  'policies[][library]': 'DEPCHECK',
  'policies[][filesList][]': '',
  'policies[][ignoreList][]': ''
}
```

How do I make nestjs convert it to "normal" object?

Answer (score -2):

The `@Body()` type is `unknown` which cannot be logged; I think it should be `uploadDto` class. try something like this:
`@Body() body:uploadDto`
and
`console.log(body)`

Comment: I did it but no effect.